# Local notification repeat every 30 second

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm going to make alarm app. After long research i'm tired to find out solution for notify every 30 or 60 second until we app open.

I would like to give reference app [Diii Notify - hourly chime](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diii-notify-hourly-chime/id1001398032?mt=8). This app notify every 30 seconds so can it possible local notification fire every 30 seconds until app open.

I have try addingTimeInterval 30 second but this is not proper solution because this is generate new notification all time. Given above app generate only one notification and repeat until app open.

**My goal is set alarm for every day and repeat notification every 30 seconds until app open**.

**Example**:- Set alarm on 8:00AM for S,M,T,W,T,F,S every day and when alarm start on 8:00AM then notify every 30 Second until app open.

Can you give me any other solution.

Comment: have you tried `notification.repeatInterval`?

Comment: Every day alarm se working fine. I have issue in repeat notify every 30 seconds.

Comment: Create a snooze button to your alarm notification. It's allows you to create another notification with the repeats.

Comment: You can try interactive notification with 2 buttons stop and snooze, On click on snooze add alarm again.

Comment: snooze is okay but if user not click on snooze then ? I want repeat if not click on snooze. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create local notification with repeat interval 30 seconds for each day You need alarm. So, for example, You will have 5 local notifications with 30 second repeat interval and when user opens app - schedule additional notifications for next weak.

As addition You can add custom buttons for alert to reschedule notifications when user choos stop alarm.

Note: You can have only about 30 scheduled local notifications for app. This isn't listed in documentation.